# How to I change an editButtonItem's tableViewController with UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I am working on an IOS application that uses `UISegmentedControl` to swap between three different tableViewControllers. These tableViewControllers are childViewControllers of a ViewController located within a navigation controller's stack.

In my viewController's `viewDidLoad`, I added code to set an edit button for my default table view controller such that

```
UIBarButtonItem *lbbi = firstController.editButtonItem;
```

When testing this out, The edit button works across all segments, however only enables editing on the firstController (as expected.)

My issue is that I need for this edit button to allow editing on my other two view controllers, either by enabling editing of all three at once, or by enabling editing of the tableViewController that is visible via use of the `UISegmentedControl`.

So far, here is what I have attempted:

```
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = navItem.leftBarButtonItem;

UITableViewController *firstController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstController"];
UITableViewController *secondController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondController"];
UITableViewController *thirdController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdController"];

 switch (segment.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        self.firstView.hidden = YES;
        self.secondView.hidden = NO;
        self.thirdView.hidden=YES;
        editButton = secondController.editButtonItem;
        break;
    case 1:
        self.firstView.hidden = NO;
        self.secondView.hidden = YES;
        self.thirdView.hidden = YES;
        editButton = firstController.editButtonItem;
        break;
    case 2:
        self.firstView.hidden = YES;
        self.secondView.hidden = YES;
        self.thirdView.hidden=NO;
        editButton = thirdController.editButtonItem;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

This does not seem to be changing the `editButtonItem` that is displayed, and I am stuck wondering what I can do to fix this.

Comment: Why do you need 3 edit buttons? Just put the edit button in the navigation bar, intercept the action, and then enable edit mode on the selected table view when the button is pressed.

Comment: How would I go about enabling the edit mode on the selected table view? This is the part I am confused about.

I tried using

        UIBarButtonItem *lbbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit
                                                                         target:self
                                                                         action:@selector(toggleEditingMode:)];

to intercept the action but I get an error when doing so.

Comment: My edit action for each of the table views are effectively the same, except I cannot figure out a way to change which table view the button sends to edit mode, outside of my viewDidLoad (if I replace firstController with secondController or thirdController in UIBarButtonItem *lbbi = firstController.editButtonItem;)

Comment: In your action method, you can use a switch statement to determine the selected segment and then turn editing mode on for that table ie. [firstController.table setEditing:YES].

Comment: In my action method, I tried implementing this, however none of my tables go into editing mode.
I could not use .table (property was not found) so I tried .tableView and just [firstController setEditing:YES animated:YES] with no success.

Comment: Sorry I meant .tableView. So it should be [firstController.tableView setEditing:YES]